# Two initial values for reduce array method?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

```js
const result = [1,2,3,4,5].reduce((acc,cur) => (acc[+(cur % 2 !== 0)] += cur, acc),  [0, 0])

console.log(result)
```

It is supposed to sum up the even values and the odd values in the array but how can we have 2 different initializers for the initial values? There are 2 commas at the end of the reduce method, how do they work in this case?

Comment: You are confusing the comma operator that returns the array...

Comment: Why are you converting a boolean to a number?  `[+(boolean expression)]` doesn't make sense

Comment: @Taplar, otherwise you need an object with `true` and `false` keys.

Comment: Why have that at all?  The mod is already going to return 0 or 1.  @NinaScholz

Comment: @Taplar, it's not my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are confusing the comma operator in the function. Below it is written without the fat arrow syntax with the implicit return.

```js
var res = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].reduce(function(acc, cur) {
  acc[+(cur % 2 !== 0)] += cur;
  return acc
}, [0, 0]);

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

In reality, you have only one start value for the accumulator, an array.

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5].reduce(
    (acc, cur) => (acc[+(cur % 2 !== 0)] += cur, acc),
    [0, 0]
)
```